# Menu flow is wrong in android mobile phones

Tags: android, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have one word-press [site](http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/) ,the menu flow of the site is working fine in desktop and i-phone , but flow is wrong in all android phones .

the problem is :

i have a main menu "courses" and sub menu under courses is "school programs".

when ever i click "courses" then the page "school programs" will load aromatically instead of "courses" page .

and i am clear that this problem is with android mobiles only .

code is :

```
  <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-36">
  <a href="http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/courses/"><span>Courses</span></a>

  <div class="sub-menu-wrapper">
  <ul class="sub-menu">

  <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><a href="http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/school-programs/"><span>School Programs</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-66"><a href="http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/womens-self-defence/"><span>Women’s self defence</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-67"><a href="http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/security-programs/"><span>Security Programs</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68"><a href="http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/business-workshops/"><span>Business Workshops</span></a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-4780" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4780"><a href="http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/instructor-courses/"><span>Krav Maga Instructor Course</span></a></li>

</ul>

</div>
</li>
```

site URL : http://www.kravmagaoz.com.au/

any help .

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is some overlapping of your div of `<li>` tag so you need to check the css and add updated code in @media query.
Thanks

Comment: i didn't find any overlapping of <li> in my code . (can you please check i have updated my question )

Comment: can you please send the url

Comment: any use full hints